# Polymer 1.0 a/custom element under toolbar clicking bug

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am encountering some problems with a custom element created by me, called `<little-game></little-game>`.

This is `<little-game></little-game>` template code :

```
<template>
<a href="{{link}}">
<paper-material elevation="1">
  <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
  <iron-image src="{{img_url}}"></iron-image>
  <div id="description">{{name}}</div>
  <div id="category">{{category}}</div>
</paper-material>
</a></template>
```

And the :host css of this element:

```
:host {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Those `<little-game></little-game>` elements are displayed in a page and inside this page i have a `<paper-scroll-header-panel>` and a `<paper-toolbar>`. The problem is when i scroll down and the `.tall` `<paper-toolbar>` gets smaller, i can click through the `<paper-toolbar>` on `<little-game>`/`<paper-ripple>` element.
`<paper-ripple>` css :

```
paper-ripple {
z-index:1;}
```

mainToolbar html :

```
<paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall">
      <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <!-- Toolbar icons -->
      <!--paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button-->
      <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
      <!-- Application name -->
      <div class="middle middle-container center horizontal layout">
        <div class="app-name">App title</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Application sub title -->
      <div class="bottom bottom-container center horizontal layout">
        <div class="bottom-title paper-font-subhead">App subtitle</div>
      </div>
    </paper-toolbar>
```

mainToolbar css :

```
#mainToolbar {
z-index:3;}
```

---

## So the main problem is about that i can click the `<a href="#"><little-game></little-game></a>` element through the toolbar.

---

There is an image to understand what i am talking about in a better way:
[image: Image that explains a Polymer-Project issue about z-indexing]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to cancel the tap event from propagating through, try adding an on-tap event handler on the paper-toolbar e.g.

```
<paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall" on-tap="{{cancelEvent}}">
```

then add the function to cancel it

```
cancelEvent: function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```